# Why does non-parametric approach break down when the joint distribution is estimated by a finite data sample?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, boosting, approximation, function

I am currently reading the paper on Gradient Boosting Machines - J. H. Friedman, “Greedy function approximation: A gradient boosting machine,” Ann. Stat., vol. 29, no. 5, pp. 1189–1232, 2001, doi: 10.1214/aos/1013203451.

There it is stated that if the non-parametric approach is taken and the numerical optimisation performed in the function space, then the non-parametric approach breaks down when the joint distribution $(y, \bf{x})$ is estimated by a finite data sample. This reasoning is provided on page 1132. Can someone explain why is that so?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]